# flex interfering with bootstrap4

Tags: flask, pagination

I'm using Pagination from flask_paginate. Passing css_framework='bootstrap4'
to Pagination.
In CSS, I have used flex.
In html {{ pagination.links }} does not show up.
How can this be resolved ?

Comment: Is it that Flexbox does not go along with Bootstrap?